# Estimate run time given widget has run a given time without failure

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given the following distribution of the fraction of widgets running over time, how do I calculate the expected run life of a widget (*d_f* days) given that it has already run *d_c* days?

My widget reliability is described with a beta distribution.

TIA. Would appreciate specific Excel formulas or examples. I've been out of school a while.

[image]

Comment: Hint: consider the probability distribution given that x > d_c. That conditional distribution will be a multiple of the original one and its value from d_c to infinity will be 1.